# What to join on

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table which associates an id to a latitude and a longitude.

For every id in that table, I'm trying find closest ids, and store them in another table with travel time, either if the route doesn't already exists or if the travel time is shorter (a route exists if there is an entry in `transfers`)

I'm currently using :

```
6371 * SQRT(POW( RADIANS(stop_lon - %lon) * COS(RADIANS(stop_lat + %lat)/2), 2) + POW(RADIANS(stop_lat - %lat), 2)) AS distance
```

To find this distance.

It does work pretty well, however I don't know what to join on (for the self join).

How should I do ?

Here 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' for the different tables which are usefull here :

```
CREATE TABLE `stops` (
  `stop_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `stop_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `stop_desc` text,
  `stop_lat` decimal(20,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_lon` decimal(20,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stop_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `stop_name` (`stop_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `stop_desc` (`stop_desc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1

CREATE TABLE `transfers` (
  `transfer_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_stop_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `to_stop_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `transfer_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transfer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `transfer_id` (`transfer_id`),
  KEY `to_stop_id` (`to_stop_id`),
  KEY `from_stop_id` (`from_stop_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81810 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
FROM transfers AS a
JOIN transfers AS b  ON b.from_stop_id = to_stop_id
```

There is to be a third table?  And it does not parallel either of the existing ones?  Let me see if I have the right model:  `stops` is like airports.  `transfers` is like waiting in an airport for your next leg of a flight.  But `transfers` fails to have the `stop_id` of itself; this is confusing.  And the `third_table` would be the flight time/distance between stops?

Or maybe a `transfer` is just a flight from one airport to another?  And there is no delay while waiting for the next leg?

Other notes:

```
PRIMARY KEY              (`transfer_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `transfer_id` (`transfer_id`),
```

Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`, the latter is redundant (and wasteful); `DROP` it.

`decimal(20,16)` is overkill.

```
Datatype           Bytes       resolution
------------------ -----  --------------------------------
DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4)     7    16 m     52 ft  Houses/Businesses
DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)     9    16cm    1/2 ft  Friends in a mall
DECIMAL(20,16)        20    microscopic
```